# ajax get and insert with php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I have a page that has a form on it, when I click a button on the page it sends 3 variables to a layer(page_ref, template_ref, and box_id) via a javascript call.

Then with ajax I get some content from the mysql db with the variables and insert this into a text area on the layer.

The layer has a save button and when I click that I want to save the content of the textarea back to the db.

I can fill the textarea from the db no problem but am having problems pushing is back to the db.

The problem I have is sending the javascript variables to the ajax update page as they need to be passed to php varriables.

heres what I have

on the main page I call a javascript function

```
 edit_box('show',i,'<? echo $page_ref; ?>','<? echo $template_ref; ?>');
```

in the layer I have this

```
<style type="text/css">
 #popupbox
  { 
   padding:0;
   width: 99%;
   height: auto;
   margin: 0px auto;    
   position:absolute;
   background: #FBFBF0; 
   border: solid #000000 2px; 
   z-index: 9000; 
   font-family: arial; 
   visibility: hidden; 
  }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://js.nicedit.com/nicEdit-latest.js"></script>
<script>
 //Browser Support Code
 function get_edit_content(box_id,page_ref,template_ref)
   {
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("edit_content").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    var area1 = new nicEditor({fullPanel : true}).panelInstance("edit_content",{hasPanel : true});  
    }
  }

  var queryString = "?box_id=" + box_id + "&page_ref=" + page_ref + "&template_ref=" + template_ref;

  xmlhttp.open("GET","get_content.php" + queryString,true);
  xmlhttp.send();
 }


 $("#sub").click( function() 
  {
     $.post( $("#myForm").attr("action"), 
     $("#myForm :input").serializeArray(), 
     function(info)
       { 
        $("#result").html(info); 
       });
    clearInput();
   });

$("#myForm").submit( function() 
  {
    return false;   
  });

 function clearInput() 
   {
$("#myForm :input").each( function() 
      {
    $(this).val('');
  });
    }     


function edit_box(showhide,box_id,page_ref,template_ref)
  {
   if(showhide == "show")
      { 
    get_edit_content(box_id,page_ref,template_ref);
       document.getElementById('popupbox').style.visibility="visible";
      }
    else if(showhide == "hide")
      {
        document.getElementById('popupbox').style.visibility="hidden";      
      } 
   }  
</script>

 <div id="popupbox">
   <form id="myForm" action="update_textarea.php" method="post"> 
    <input type="hidden" name="page_ref" value="<? echo $page_ref; ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="template_ref" value="<? echo $template_ref; ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="box_id" value="<? echo $box_id; ?>" />
    <textarea name="edit_content" id="edit_content"  style="width: 500px; height:500px;"></textarea>
    <center><a href="javascript:edit_box('hide');">close</a></center> 
    <button id="sub">Save</button>
   </form>
</div>
```

then I have get_contents page

```
<?php   
include("connect.php"); 
$page_ref = $_GET['page_ref'];  
$template_ref = $_GET['template_ref'];
$box_id = $_GET['box_id'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM site_content WHERE page_ref='$page_ref' AND template_ref='$template_ref' AND box_id='$box_id' AND box_type='text'";  
$result = mysql_query($sql);  
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))  
 {  
  echo "<p>".$row['content']."</p>";  
 }  
?>
```

and finally the update_textarea page

```
<?
include("connect.php"); 
$page_ref = $_POST['page_ref'];  
$template_ref = $_POST['template_ref'];
$box_id = $_POST['box_id'];
$edit_content = $_POST['edit_content']; 
if(mysql_query("UPADTE site_content SET content='$edit_content' WHERE page_ref='$page_ref' AND template_ref='$template_ref' AND box_id='$box_id' AND box_type='text'"))
 {
   echo "Successfully Inserted";
 }
else
 {
  echo "Insertion Failed";
 }
?>
```

Comment: Since you're using jQuery, why are you using that horribly verbose Javascript for the AJAX call, instead of `$.get()`?

Comment: my jscript and jquery are not great and I am using code that I have found online and tried to change it to match my needs

Comment: I dont know which part you are talking about, any clues?

Comment: The text area you're asking about is the nicEdit widget? The documentation of its `onSave:` option is [here](http://wiki.nicedit.com/w/page/525/Saving%20via%20AJAX)

Comment: I dont want to use the nicEdit onSave. I want to push the 3 variables and the content of the textarea to the db using ajax

Comment: That seems to be what you're doing when you set `queryString`. The only thing you're missing is that you should call `encodeURIComponent()` to encode special characters properly.

Comment: Never mind that, I now see that's for `get_contents`, not `update_textarea`.

Comment: I think you just need to change the `#sub` click handler to use `serialize()` instead of `serializeArray()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realised that i needed to set the values of the hidden inputs in the ajax call after

```
 document.getElementById("edit_content").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
```

by adding

```
 document.getElementById("box_id").value = box_id;
```

etc